# Inventory management view

Tags: inventory

I am working on an Inventory management application for telephone numbers. Numbers are divided into four product types and have a lot of interlinked information.

For e.g.

1. a user can have all four product types.
2. each product type can have multiple telephone numbers, TNs are always sold in the format of blocks. Like a customer will purchase numbers in ranges from 123###01 - 123###100, so 99 numbers.
3. telephone numbers can have data, voice or both plans.
4. numbers can also have extra information like billing details, address, pricing etc

We have observed that user do not remember the product type but numbers or can use some unique IDs to get the info.

My question is - I am planning to have a single open search on landing page which will allow user to search five attributes max like product type, telephone number, status etc.

Another way is to direct customers to the dashboard where we can list down latest 20 records which I believe is not a good idea because they have to again do the filtering.

What do you all uxers think of it? Also, is there any inventory tool for referral?

Edit 1-

Let me add more details- Application is for B2B customers and product categories could be similar to subscription plans(max 4). Generally, customers will be navigated through newsletters or direct website, so as per user interview findings, we observed that customers prefer digits(telephone number, transaction id etc)to search as it will fetch closer results unlike open ended attributes like categories, address etc. Also note that we have two types of user types 1)customer (less number of plans) 2) partners ( managing multiple customers)

Comment: Could you please clarify this line: "*We have observed that user do not remember the product type but numbers or can use some unique IDs to get the info.*" Do you mean that the users are failing to remember both the product types *and* the phone numbers, and that instead they're using some other unique IDs?

Comment: @maxathousand added details.